# How can I validate my jdbc connection whether the data base is up running without executing sql query

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm working with spring jdbc, In my case I have to execute a query and refresh cache only when data base is up running for this I'm not finding any method appropriate to call on Connection object.

Comment: Maybe use a 'fake' query like 'SELECT 1 from DUAL'

Comment: What's the database?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring JdbcTemplate you could perhaps use:

`public <T> T execute(ConnectionCallback<T> action) throws DataAccessException`

> Execute a JDBC data access operation, implemented as callback action
> working on a JDBC Connection. This allows for implementing arbitrary
> data access operations, within Spring's managed JDBC environment: that
> is, participating in Spring-managed transactions and converting JDBC
> SQLExceptions into Spring's DataAccessException hierarchy.
>
> The callback action can return a result object, for example a domain object or a collection of domain objects.

[jdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html).

You could execute an action once the connection is established such a simple query perhaps.

Let me know if that helps.